# How can I remove gap between div and span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this jsFiddle you can see a div with some span element in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/9H9Tg/1/

Why there is a gap between first line and the top div border line? Is it a default line-height? I have set no line-height in my css class.

http://h33i.img-up.net/Bildschirm4fda.png

How can I remove this gap in different browsers also with different fonts?

```
    <div id="draggable-title2">
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: verdana; font-size: 40px; padding-top: 0px;display: inline-block;">
    Hello World 
    <br />next line
    </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: The browser will set line-height: normal, even without you specifying it.  You can make it lower to reduce space between lines, but I wouldn't use it for this purpose as the text won't read well.  Negative top margin seems a better approach.

Comment: @davidpauljunior Agreed, well said!

Comment: [Agreed ;) - @davidpauljunior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656088/how-can-i-remove-gap-between-div-and-span/19656289#19656289)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only fix the top spacing, check the below solution.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9H9Tg/7/)**

**The Code Change:**

```
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: verdana; font-size: 40px; padding-top: 0px;display: inline-block; margin-top:-10px;">
```

Comment: Ah, I agree more with this solution more then any other.

Comment: nice it works. But how can I calculate the margin -10px? I don't think that this works with every font-size and every font.

Comment: It works for all @sja87. Try in %age if the font size is in %age and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Add this in **css**

```
span{
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9H9Tg/5/)

Or you use `margin` like,

```
span{
    padding:0;
    line-height:33px;
    margin:-2px auto;
}
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/9H9Tg/9/)

Comment: This is just pushing the lines into each-other. Wouldn't recommend it. Here is what will happen if you use this method. [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/9H9Tg/8/) That is a very long "L".

Comment: @Ruddy in that case you can use `line-height:33px`, it depends.

Comment: This is then causing a bigger gap at the top and the text isn't much better. It's just playing an unnecessary balancing game. This does not seem like the best way to fix this.

Comment: Use `line-height:33px;margin:-2px auto`

Comment: So you may aswell just use the solution that @Nathan Lee said. Makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using css `line-height`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9H9Tg/4/)**

```
 <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: verdana; font-size: 40px; padding-top: 0px;display: inline-block;line-height: 30px;">
```